# JavaScript Not Returning Data But No Error Either

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am calling a php file that queries my database and returns a result.  I have verified that the php file accurately returns the data as needed, but my calling page is not updated from the JavaScript.

What do I need to alter in my syntax below so that the returned value is returned on page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function boostion()
{
var xhr;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
     xhr.open("GET", "QueryDB.php", true); 
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
     xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
    function display_data() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {     
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
I have also opened Developer Options in Chrome and checked the Console and there are no errors or issues displayed, everything is a success!

**Edit 2**
I tried to use the JQuery approach below and used this syntax - but I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

Syntax:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js" 
    integrity="sha256-5i/mQ300M779N2OVDrl16lbohwXNUdzL/R2aVUXyXWA=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
 $.get("QueryDB.php", function(data, status){
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
});
});
</script>
```

**Edit 3**
This is my php syntax that runs the sql syntax and echo result that I want to have returned from the javascript

```
<?php
    $option = array(); 

    $option['driver']   = 'mssql';
    $option['host']     = 'host';
    $option['user']     = 'user';       
    $option['password'] = 'password';   
    $option['database'] = 'database';     
    $option['prefix']   = '';            

    $db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
    $result = $db->getQuery(true);
    $result->select($db->quoteName(array('trackandfieldresults')));
    $result->from($db->quoteName('[TrackData]')); 
    $db->setQuery($result); 
    $row = $db->loadRowList();
    echo $row['0']
?>
```

Comment: Don't use jquery if you are not aware of it

Answer (score 0):

Use `xhr.send();`
If it is a `GET` request, you have to apply the query string in in `xhr.open` and you dont have to set `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: It is a get request as I am pressing a button and the php is querying my database and returning data.  I will look at xhr.send()

Comment: Besides `send()` method, don't forget to put the function outside which is better

Comment: `xhr.send' is required to send the data

Comment: I have the querystring placed in my QueryDB.php.  All I need to do is a working method of calling it and returning the result

Comment: QueryString means form data. If you have to pass any value, then only you need it. You can try `xhr.send();` after `xhr.open`.

Comment: Remove the `Content-type` header

Comment: I removed the content-type line and I have in this order, xhr.onreadystatechange
xhr.open
xhr.send   -- which presents no error, but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: Navigate to host/QueryDB.php and check whether the $row[0] is shown or not.

Comment: If not, it is a problem with your db connection.

Comment: Yes - the QueryDB.php will return the result as it should.  My issue is reading that result with XMLHTTP or JavaScript :)

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200){ 
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      }

Comment: //dont use else part. Because the readyState will change 4 times and only at last time, the readyState will be 4. Before that, 3 times the alert will pop

Comment: That gives me an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200){ document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText; } } //replace your onreadystatechange and the function below it with this code.

Comment: No error, however my div is not populated with xhr.responseText

Comment: Open console and navigate to **network** tab. Click on the request in the left and click response in right pane. Take a screenshot and add it here

Comment: There is no response, when I click that tab it shows the same thing as the preview

Comment: try my another answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a faster approach using JQuery.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $.get("QueryDB.php", function(data, status){
    //Do whatever you want here
    });
});
```

This should do the Job. Your approach is old and kind of complicated to       debug

Comment: *Emberassment* I do not know how to use JQuery - what reference would I add, and how do I place between the <script> tags?

Comment: Learning jquery requires time, by now don't use it yet until you learned.

Comment: It's is simple. google Jquery CDN then include it in your page like regular javascript. The logic is the same just different form of writing it. For putting data in your HTML, You can select the element by id and use the .text() or .val() function to append the result. It's easy. No need to append the script in your php code.

Comment: In the //Do whatever you want here, how do I read the response from my QueryDB.php?  It will be a single response, like "Alpha Bravo"

Comment: `data` is the response

Comment: I get an error of Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

Comment: Use $(window).on('load', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

Comment: @oakinyelure - good catch.  Fixing that presents this error Uncaught ReferenceError: boostion is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: @oakinyelure - my most recent edit - #2 shows the current syntax I have.

Answer (score 0):

first, the scripts should be inside the HTML before the ending body tag. then you open another file and write your code in it. JQUERY does not have script tag. Sp you are creating an external javascript file for the script. No script tag needed. Now use this format.

```
$(window).on('load', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var dat = //the content you are trying to load
$.get('middleware.php', dat, function(data){
$('#selector').html(data)
});

})
```

Comment: How do I reference the external javascript file so that the php knows what this syntax is?

Comment: in your HTML, you have <body>//put jquery cdn here , then put your own script <script src = 'yourscript.js'></script></body> It's Ajax, it would respond to your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function boostion(){
  var xhr;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "QueryDB.php", true);   
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(xhr);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
<button onclick="boostion();">Load</button>
```

Comment: Still nothing returned.  All I see is readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: ""...

Comment: there is a XMLHttpRequest in bottom of all and click on the object. Take a screenshot and add it

Comment: What do you mean in bottom of all?  I do not see it.

Comment: in console, you can see 4 entries of XMLHttpRequest. open the last one by clicking the expand arrow

Comment: I only had 1 entry of XMLHttpRequest

Comment: edited. Now your console will show the XHR object 4 times. click the last one in it